Implementing Multifunctional API Features with Drizzle ORM in PostgreSQL: Need Guidance on Creating a Single Class for Filtering, Sorting, Pagination?
In my previous project, I used Mongoose with MongoDB. I created a single class to chain multiple functions, making the API more efficient. With this class, any API could become multifunctional, enabling features like filtering, sorting, selecting fields, pagination, etc.
For example: url/api/employee?sort=name&select=id,name,email&page=2&limit=10
Here,

sort sorts the names in ascending order.

select returns only the id, name, and email in the response.

page indicates the page number.

limit sets the result limit per page.


I achieved all these features using one line by creating a class file in Mongoose. For instance:
// Build the query
const features = new APIFeatures(
  Employee.find(),
  req.query
)
  .sort()
  .select()
  .paginate();

// Execute the query
const employees = await features.query;

Here, APIFeature is the class I created, which takes two parameters:

Employee.find() - the first parameter.

req.query - the second parameter.


The implementation of APIFeatures is provided below.
Now, since I've switched to PostgreSQL and am using Drizzle ORM, I want to achieve the same functionality by creating a single class. However, I'm facing difficulties.
If anyone can help, I would be very thankful.
class APIFeatures {
  constructor(query, queryString) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryString = queryString;
  }

  sort() {
    if (this.queryString.sort) {
      const sortBy = this.queryString.sort.split(",").join(" ");
      this.query = this.query.sort(sortBy);
    } else {
      this.query = this.query.sort("name");
    }

    return this;
  }

  select() {
    if (this.queryString.fields) {
      const fields = this.queryString.select.split(",").join(" ");
      this.query = this.query.select(fields);
    } else {
      this.query = this.query.select("-__v");
    }

    return this;
  }

  paginate() {
    const page = this.queryString.page * 1 || 1;
    const limit = this.queryString.limit * 1 || 10;
    const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

    this.query = this.query.skip(skip).limit(limit);

    return this;
  }
}

module.exports = APIFeatures;


Could you restate the question? I'm sure I exactly understand what you're asking here... Drizzle provides an API itself; e.g. if you need your APIFeatures class's select run a select, use the Drizzle query or select API within your method,
const result = await db.select().from(users);
